# How to fetch data from two tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in SQL Server

**tbl_posting_job_info**

[image]

**tbl_jobseeker_applied_job**

[image]

In this two table `job_posting_id` and `applied_job_id` primary key in respective table

In `tbl_posting_job_info` field `job_posting_id` is refer as FK in `tbl_jobseeker_applied_job`

So, my problem is that how to fetch top 25 `company_id` which are most apply by `jobseeker`?

Thanks.

Comment: Your title is too general and doesn't describe your question well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 25 COUNT(b.applied_job_id), a.CompanyID
FROM tbl_posting_job_info a INNER JOIN
tbl_jobseeker_applied_job b ON a.job_posting_id = b.job_posting_id
GROUP BY a.CompanyID
ORDER BY Count(b.applied_job_id) DESC
```

Comment: i got erroe `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.` @JonH

Comment: Sorry use GROUP BY then ORDER BY see my edit.